# Htaccess Code not working after changing Server

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I was using this code in htaccess to strip any directory to index.php

```
RewriteRule ^.(index.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

For instance

```
http://www.example.com/toys/index.php
http://www.example.com/battery/upload/index.php
http://www.example.com/xyz/photos/index.php
```

It was changing redirecting all of them to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php
```

Now when i changed my server - this code is causing 404 pages
Is there any alternate modification which can be advised to remodify the code so as to strip any line or directory after domain and before index.php

Comment: Check your vhost and ensure AllowOverride is turned on (thus allowing your .htaccess file to be processed). A simple way to check that the .htaccess file is being parsed is to write a load of nonsense into it. If you don't get a 500 error, it's not being used. Also check  that the rewrite module is installed and enabled.

Comment: Hello - checked that, rewrite mode is enabled . Also other htaccess code strings are workings, except the one mentioned in question

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `RewriteRule ^.+?(index\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]` instead?

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, On closely observing it was found that the rule is applied on backend administrator section too - due to which component not found - 404 and 500 error happening. How to create an exception that administrator folder does not get impacted due to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create exception for `administrator` folder you can do:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!administrator/).+?(index\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thats brilliance. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should do the job:

```
RewriteRule ^.+/index.php$ index.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

P.S. I like this tool to test my rewrite rules: [Link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: No - its not causing . This code is causing the error -s This webpage has a redirect loop, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS